# Apple iMac mid 2011 Graphical Artifacts

Tags: gpu, osx-lion, visual-artifacts

[image: Widgets]
[image: Desktop Icons]

I bought a brand new iMac mid 2011, and from time to time I've get these artifacts.
What could be the cause?

It looks like this when the temperature of the Graphical Diode = 77-80C, but when I was on Snow Leopard, I don't remember these artifacts. After upgrading to Lion, I can't work normally.

Comment: I guess you should return it and ask for a replacement.

Comment: There was a recall on the 2011 27" iMac graphics card.  See here: http://support.apple.com/kb/TS5167